# Animated Color Ramp Not Showing in Viewport

Tags: animation, game-engine, 3d-view, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm an experienced user and have stumbled upon an issue that I can't wrap my head around. I have a very simple node setup. A base material, to a color ramp to an output.

[image]

The position of white marker is animated using a driver that reads info from a baked f-curve. I can confirm that driver works properly and position value changes according to my curve.

My problem is that the method works properly if rendered, however for my game I need to use GLSL/Viewport and consequently what I see in viewport is what I get but the changes do not show in viewport. Changes only appear after I click on the marker in the color ramp.

Basically viewport updates only if colorramp marker is clicked by the user.

I was wondering if there is a workaround/script for this, that forces the viewport to update/refresh properly from frame to frame.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to the site :) You might try using the [experimental new depsgraph](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/Animation#Dependency_Graph) and see if that helps at all

Comment: In this forum <https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?399511-Force-material-update-OpenGL-render-active-viewport> you can found a script that helps to solve this problem. :D